# Get footer to go to bottom of display

Tags: html, css

I got this footer im wanting to go to the bottom of my display and stay there (not so much a fixed position as i want it to change with the content that is in it). at the moment its made to be a sticky footer and moves with the content, im just wanting it to be constantly positioned at the bottom of the display so there isnt this weird floating gap with a huge space beneath it.

HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Home</title>
            <!--===================================================css links===================================================!-->
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,500,400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900,100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href="css/default_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="css/contact_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </head>   
        <body>
            <!--===================================================Header===================================================!-->
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="headerwrap">
                    <div class="social">    
                        <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/deviant.png"></a>
                        <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/yt.png"/></a>
                        <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/fb.png"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <!--close social!-->
                    <div class="header">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <img src="images/logo.png" />
                        </div>
                        <!--close logo-->
                    </div>
                    <!--close header!-->
                    <div class="menu">
                        <ul class="menutxt">
                            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--close menu!-->
                </div>
                <!--close headerwrap!-->
                <!--===================================================Contact===================================================!-->
                <div class="toptxt">
                    <div id="test2">
                        <p class="infotxt">Get in touch...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="detailwrap">
                    <div class="contactspace"></div>
                    <!--close contactspace!-->
                    <div class="contact">
                        <img class="move2" class="hover" src="images/me2.png">
                        <p class="text">Luke Babich</p>
                    </div>
                    <!--close contact!-->
                    <div class="contact">
                        <img class="move2" class="hover" src="images/phone.png">
                        <p class="text">+27 72 836 0954</p>
                    </div>
                    <!--close contact!-->
                    <div class="contact">
                        <img class="move2" class="hover" src="images/mail.png">
                        <p class="text">lukerbab@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>
                    <!--close contact!-->
                    <div class="contactspace"></div>
                    <!--close contactspace!-->
                </div>
                <!--close detailwrap!-->
                <!--===================================================Footer===================================================!-->
                <div class="footerwrap2">
                    <p class="foottxt">Designed and developed by Luke Babich- All Rights Reserved ©2015</p>
                </div>
                <!--close footerwrap!-->
            </div>
            <!--close wrapper!-->
        </body>
    </html>

</i>

Layout CSS:
```

```
@charset "utf-8";
/*---------------------------- Body and Default ----------------------------*/
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#171717;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:#CCC;
} 
a{
    color:#000;
    transition:300ms;
}
a:hover {
    color:#000;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*---------------------------- Main Wrapper ----------------------------*/
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:100%; 
}
/*---------------------------- Header ----------------------------*/
.header{
    position:relative;
    min-height:180px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right:225px;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #333 ;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #333 ;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #000;
    z-index:200;
}
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    min-width:60px; 
    top:4%;
}
.logo img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100%;
}
.social{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-width:20px; 
    top:15px;
    right:1%;
    z-index:500;    
}
.social img{
    float:right;
    width:35px;
    display: block;
    padding:0 0 0px 15px;
}
img.move {
    bottom:0px;
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.44, 1.2);
}
img.move:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.4, 1.4, 1.4);    
}
/*---------------------------- Menu ----------------------------*/
.menu{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:200px;
    z-index:401;
}
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    display: inline;
    list-style:none;
    padding:1%;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
li a{
    color:#CCC;
    transition:300ms;
}
li a:hover {
    color:#900;
}
.menutxt{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size:1.8vw;
    font-weight:400;
    z-index:300;
}
/*---------------------------- Footer Text ----------------------------*/
.foottxt{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    background:#070707;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding:15px 0;
    font-size:0.7em;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:200;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Content CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/*---------------------------- Content ----------------------------*/
.toptxt{
    margin-top:130px;
    width:100%;
}
/*.contactwrap{
    width:100%;                 change back if cant figure it out
    margin-top:60px;
}*/ 
.detailwrap{
    margin-top:100px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center; /* center align .contacts */
}
/* clearfix */
.detailwrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.infotxt{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight:400;
}
.contact {
    display: inline-block; /* make it possible to use text-align */
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 180px; /* avoid 15% being making the contacts less than 115px */
    margin: 4% 1% 10% 0;
}
.contact img{
    width: 90px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%; /*bring back if needed*/
    height: auto;  /*bring back if needed*/
}
.contact .text {
    top:-15px;
    text-align:center;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.contact:hover .text {
    animation: fadein 2s;
    visibility:visible;
}
img.move2 {
    bottom:0px;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.44, 1.2);
}
img.move2:hover {
    -moz-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -ms-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -o-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    transform: translate(0px, -10px)    
}
/*---------------------------- Footer ----------------------------*/
.footerwrap2{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    z-index:501;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px 0px #000;
}
/*---------------------------- Textfader ----------------------------*/
#test2 p {
    animation: fadein 5s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 5s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 5s; /* Opera */
    transition: opacity 5s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

i wasnt too sure what code was needed and had 2 style sheets that may affect the footer div......So basically im wanting .footerwrap2 to be at the bottom of the browser even after device and browser size changes.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand - you say `I got this footer im wanting to go to the bottom of my display and stay there `  then you say `not so much a fixed position as i want it to change with the content that is in it` and then you say `im just wanting it to be constantly positioned at the bottom of the display` - ???

Comment: basically if its fixed content will go under it. I want it to move with the content while being at the bottom completely.

Answer (score 0):

I copied all your code into a local page and added the following lines:

For the footerwrap2, I changed the position from relative to absolute, and positioned it at the bottom of the page.

```
position:absolute; bottom: 0;
```

As you've probably already found, that wasn't enough. The body, and wrapper div have no idea how TALL the content page is, therefore, they determine the size based on content.

I solved the problem by adding the following style to the main wrapper (.wrapper)

```
height: 100vh;
```

This uses the latest CSS3 view height so it will only work on modern browsers. If you must maintain compatibility with older browsers, you'll need to set the height for the body, wrapper, and possibly the html tags to be 100%.

I tested it locally and it works like a champ. If you can't get it to work, I'll move it to a fiddle.

Good Luck!

Comment: hey thanks man!....do you maybe think there is a way to do it with a jquery or something of the sort? to test for the height of the page and then move it accordingly?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. You'd have to bind to a resize event of something that you know will change size when the user changes the browser size. That means, you'd have to set body height to 100% and I'm not sure the responsiveness would be as snappy as the straight CSS solution. In my experience, it's a good idea to let the browser do as much work for you as possible. Is there a specific reason you're looking to use jQuery instead of CSS?